# QTableWidget- automatic formula driven cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

Is it possible to make one cell a formula driven cell and have it update automatically? Similar to Excel.

For example, I want user to fill out two cells, and then a third cell will automatically divide when user fills both cells. I'd like it to be NOT connected to a button.

QTable Screenshot

[image]

Code for TableWidget:

```
self.tableWidget = {}
for i in range(int(self.numberLine.text())):
    self.tableWidget[i] = QTableWidget()
    self.tableWidget[i].setRowCount(5)
    self.tableWidget[i].setColumnCount(3)
    self.tableWidget[i].setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['OEM (Case {})'.format(i+1), 'ZVI (Case {})'.format (i+1), 'Improvement % '])
    self.tableWidget[i].setVerticalHeaderLabels(['Flow (MMSCFD)', 'HP', 'Specific Power (HP/MMSCFD)', 'Discharge Temp (F)', ''])
    self.tableWidget[i].setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(480, 180))
    self.gridLayout_14.addWidget(self.tableWidget[i])
```

Comment: Could you explain what cells you need to operate and how?

Comment: In the drawing you have, do you want the third cell to be equal to the second one between the first one?

Comment: Cell (2,0) or 'Specific Power(HP/MMSCFD)' needs to update when user inputs values in Cell (0,0)- 'Flow (MMSCFD) and Cell (1,0) - 'HP'. Cell (2,0) takes values from both Cell(0,0) and Cell(1,0). It divides Cell(1,0)/Cell(0,0) or in otherwords it takes HP/Flow(MMSCFD).

Comment: If you are looking at screenshot, I want 3rd cell to be equal to 2nd cell/1st cell

Comment: One query will all cells have only numeric entries?

Comment: Yes, they will be floats

Comment: Do you have a defined range? How many decimals do you want to display?

Comment: Try with my answer. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An elegant solution is to create a custom class that inherits from `QTableWidget`, where you connect the `itemChanged` signal, this is issued each time the cell changes value (this returns the changed item but will use it only to verify that the default columns are the ones have been changed).

In addition to not having problems that the user places different values to a floating we will use a QDoubleValidator, for that we create a custom QItemDelegate.

```
class FloatDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, _from, _to, _n_decimals, parent=None):
        QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self._from = _from
        self._to = _to
        self._n_decimals = _n_decimals

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        lineEdit = QLineEdit(parent)
        _n_decimals = 2
        validator = QDoubleValidator(self._from, self._to, self._n_decimals, lineEdit)
        lineEdit.setValidator(validator)
        return lineEdit


class CustomTableWidget(QTableWidget):
    _from = 0
    _to = 10**5
    _n_decimals = 2
    def __init__(self, i,  parent=None):
        QTableWidget.__init__(self, 5, 3, parent=parent)
        self.setItemDelegate(FloatDelegate(self._from, self._to, self._n_decimals, self))
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['OEM (Case {})'.format(i+1), 'ZVI (Case {})'.format (i+1), 'Improvement % '])
        self.setVerticalHeaderLabels(['Flow (MMSCFD)', 'HP', 'Specific Power (HP/MMSCFD)', 'Discharge Temp (F)', ''])
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(480, 180))
        self.itemChanged.connect(self.onItemChanged)

    def onItemChanged(self, item):
        # items (2, 0) = (1, 0) / (0, 0)
        if item.column() == 0 and (item.row() == 0 or item.row()==1):
            num = self.item(1, 0)
            den = self.item(0, 0)
            if num and den:
                resp = float(num.data(Qt.DisplayRole))/float(den.data(Qt.DisplayRole))
                rest_string = str(round(resp, self._n_decimals))
                it = QTableWidgetItem(rest_string, QTableWidgetItem.Type)
                self.setItem(2, 0, it)
```

Example:

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setLayout(QGridLayout())
        for i in range(2):
            self.layout().addWidget(CustomTableWidget(i))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Widget()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In your case:

```
self.tableWidget = {}
for i in range(int(self.numberLine.text())):
    self.tableWidget[i] = CustomTableWidget(i)
    self.gridLayout_14.addWidget(self.tableWidget[i])
```

Another option instead of using validators, we can change the QLineEdit to QDoubleSpinBox.

```
def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
    w = QDoubleSpinBox(parent)
    _n_decimals = 2
    w.setMinimum(self._from)
    w.setMaximum(self._to)
    w.setDecimals(self._n_decimals)
    return w
```

Comment: What exactly does method createEditor do?

Comment: Each time you edit QTableWidget text changes the widget that normally is to another appropriate, if you realize when you edit a QLineEdit appears instead of a QLabel, then createEditor is the function that creates the editing widget, in our case QLineEdit, and that QLineEdit we place the validator.

Comment: For you to understand better you can change createEditor to the new function that I added.

Comment: Is there a way to access variables from the QtDesigner made Ui class inside the CustomTableWidget class?

Comment: Have you promoted the QTableWidget in Qt Designer?

Comment: Yes, and I have a separate module named customtablewidget, how do I access values from the module it is being imported into?

Comment: Provide a mvce, I do not understand much that is what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the cell to the other cells EditingFinished signal

Comment: Considering my QTableWidget is dynamically created, how do I connect one cell to the other? self.tableWidget[i].item(1,0).EditingFinished.connect(self.tableWidget[i].item(2,0))?

Comment: Yes, the number of cells is defined, but my QTableWidget is being creating multiple times, that is why there is 'self.tableWidget[i]'. I'm searching for a way to connect the cell (1,0) to (2,0). I was asking how you connect two cells together. So that when user inputs into (1,0), cell (2,0) will divide (1,0) by another cell. Is there a document on how to connect cells using EditingFinished?

Comment: There is actually a total of 10 cells, but I only care about the first column marked as 'OEM'. There is 5 cells in 'OEM' column. Trying to divide cell (1,0)/ cell(0,0), and I want it to update as soon as user inputs a value in the row marked 'HP'

Comment: Each cell has a widget item. I think you can connect them. I would also look into deriving from QTableWidget and do the connecting there instead of outside the array of tables. Alternatively maybe it is time to look at QTableView and build your own model. The models setData() can then evaluate your formula much simpler. It would also allow you to show the same data in different views if you ever need that.